# amazon web services flow manager?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I want to schedule some nightly EMR tasks and run custom scripts :

some will require to be ran on temporary instance 
others on running servers themselves, thus will need to be ran ONLY when the cpu / memory threshold is lower than some %.

How do you go about it? without having 24hrs instance running that coordinates all this and how does this process scales?

ALSO, how do you create flow (this job needs to run AFTER that one, only if it was sucess, otherwise don't run any) and can you auto-output to S3?

Are there any examples? i came across http://aws.amazon.com/swf/ but still not sure if this is what i'm after... 
tnx

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Simple Workflow Service (SWF) is Amazon's intended solution to this sort of workflow.